# Make a 2D array in C with a variable

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I have an integer variable x that I need to use to make two 2D arrays but I get an error of "cannot allocate an array of constant size 0". After doing some research I apparently need to use malloc but I have no idea how to apply it to my currently situation.

My two arrays I need:

```
int firMat[x][5];
int secMat[5][x];
```

Comment: Are you set a value to a variable `x` before this?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Yes, a value is assigned to x before this.

Comment: Do your C Compiler support C99?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I'm using Visual Studio Pro. 2013 and from what I've read it only uses parts of C99.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int x = 2;
    int **firMat;//int firMat[x][5];
    int **secMat;//secMat[5][x];
    int i;

    firMat = malloc(x * sizeof(int*));
    for(i = 0; i< x; ++i)
        firMat[i] = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));

    secMat = malloc(5 * sizeof(int*));
    for(i = 0; i< 5; ++i)
        secMat[i] = malloc(x * sizeof(int));

    //do stuff E.g. fir[2][1] = 21;
    //release E.g.
    //for(i = 0; i< x; ++i)
    //    free(firMat[i]);
    //free(firMat);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C99, this will work. It will create a "variable-length array", sadly VLAs have been reduced to "optional" in C11.

To use `malloc` for this, typically I'd abandon the double-array notation, and treat the memory as a flat one-dimensional array, then array[i][j] becomes ptr[ i*cols + j ].

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize x like in the example below

```
#define x 2 //outside the function
```

and then use x like this

```
int firMat[x][5];
int secMat[5][x];
```